# Trying to simplify an equation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am working on an equation at the moment and my mind is playing tricks on me.
I have a few variables:

```
var infiniteCount,
    itemIndex,
    itemCount = 6,
    itemsToShow = 3,
    itemsOffScreen = itemsToShow * 3;
```

this is just an example.
I came up with an equation to work out the item index after I prepend items while reverse looping through the items (I hope that makes sense).
The equation I came up with is this:

```
itemIndex = (itemsOffscreen - (infiniteCount * 2)) + ((itemCount - infiniteCount) - 1);
```

It works. If I change the itemsToShow to 6 the index is still right.
To see the code in action, it looks like this:

```
// Set up infinite
var _setupInfinite = function (items, options) {

    // Are we infinite
    var i,
        infiniteCount,
        itemIndex,
        itemCount = items.length,
        itemsToShow = options.display.itemsToShow || itemCount,
        itemsOffscreen = itemsToShow * 3,
        isEven = items.length % 2 == 0;

    // If we are scrollable
    if (options.scrollable && options.infinite) {

        // If we need to duplicate some items
        if (itemsOffscreen > itemCount) {

            // Set our counter to the amount we need to duplicate
            infiniteCount = itemsToShow;

            // Get our index (it won't change as we are always adding to the beginning of the array)
            itemIndex = (itemsOffscreen - (infiniteCount * 2)) + ((itemCount - infiniteCount) - 1);

            // Add items to the beginning of our array
            for (i = itemsOffscreen; i > (itemsOffscreen - infiniteCount) ; i--) {

                // Copy our item
                var item = angular.copy(items[itemIndex]);
                item.active = false;

                // Add to the beginning of the array
                items.unshift(item);
            }

            // Add items to the end of our array
            for (i = 0; i < infiniteCount; i++) {

                // Get our index
                itemIndex = i + infiniteCount;

                // Copy our item
                var item = angular.copy(items[itemIndex]);
                item.active = false;

                // Add to the end of the array
                items.push(item);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

So, the problem is that expression. It just seems so complicated to me.
I am sure that it can be simplified.
So I guess I am just wondering if anyone knows how?

Comment: None of your parentheses are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using basic arithmetic simplification:

```
(itemsOffscreen - (infiniteCount * 2)) + ((itemCount - infiniteCount) - 1)
```

=

```
itemsOffScreen - infiniteCount * 2 + itemCount - infiniteCount - 1
```

=

```
itemsOffScreen + itemCount - infiniteCount * 3 - 1
```

In whatever case, you should go with the version that is most readable.

Answer (score 1):

That expression simplifies to:

```
itemIndex = itemsOffscreen + itemCount - 3*infiniteCount - 1;
```

But the original may convey the intent of the expression better.